# Numerically evaluate a series involving Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

How can I numerically evaluate the following for $n$ above one million:
$$ \sum_{k>=n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i {{n-1}\choose{i}} \left( \frac{n-1-i}{n} \right)^{k-1} k (k+1)$$?

I have tried changing the order of summation and the getting closed form for the geometric series in $k$ but the terms are large (even for $n = 100$) and I run into precision problems.

Comment: So are you adding over $n$? or $k$?

Comment: @Phicar $n$ is fixed. The sum is over $k$ and $i$.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $${n \brace k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum _{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}(k-i)^n,$$
so your expression is equal to
$$\sum _{k\geq n}\frac{(n-1)!k(k+1)}{n^{k-1}}{k-1\brace n-1}=2(n-1)!\sum _{k\geq n}\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}\binom{k+1}{2}{k-1\brace n-1},$$
if $n$ is large, then $k$ is large, so ${k-1\brace n-1}\sim \frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{(n-1)!}$ and so
$$2(n-1)!\sum _{k\geq n}\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^{k-1}(n-1)!}\binom{k+1}{2}=2\sum _{k\geq n}\left (\frac{n-1}{n}\right )^{k-1}\binom{k+1}{2}$$
now take $x=(n-1)/n,$ we complete the sum to $\infty$ and take out the finite sum getting
$$2\left (\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+1}{2}x^{k-1}-\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{2}x^{k-1}\right )=2\left (\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}-\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{2}x^{k-1}\right ),$$
recall too that taking the second derivative of  $\sum _{k=1}^{n}x^{k}$ gives you
$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1)k\cdot x^{k-1}$ but that sum is $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ and so we get
$$\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}-\frac{(n + 1)n\cdot x^{n-1}}{x-1} + \frac{2 (n+1) x^n}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{2 (-1 + x^{1 + n})}{(x-1)^3},$$
taking $x=(n-1)/n$ back we get
$$2n^3+(n + 1)n^2\cdot \left (1-\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n-1} + 2 n^2(n+1) \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right )^n - 2 n^3(-1 + \left (1-\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n+1}).$$
For $n$ as big, if I am not mistaken, your expression should be close to
$$(4-\frac{2}{e})n^3+\frac{3}{e}(n+1)n^2$$

Comment: Sharp intuition to introduce the sum definition of St2 (+1)!

Comment: @GCab Thanks! The OP itself tag them.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be different from the results I have. For $n = 100$ I get $285438.6941$. From the data I have, it should be more close to $n^{2.5}$. I don't know how good the approximation for the Stirling numbers is when $k \approx n$.

Comment: @VargaRobert Cool, can you share your data? I will double check the computation. The stirling numbers are closed to that expression, but one is kindda adding a lot of error in the sum.

Comment: This is Matlab/Octave code where I used the closed form for the geometric series. There are some results in the bottom. https://pastebin.com/iXdj06Gt

Comment: I think that there are some problems. Hoping that you do not mind, I shall put an answer starting using your steps. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not at all, thanks! (+1) I think I see one of my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comments.*

Starting from the point where @Phicar wrote
$$S_n=2\sum _{k= n}^\infty\left (\frac{n-1}{n}\right )^{k-1}\binom{k+1}{2}$$ we have
$$S_n=\sum_{k= n}^\infty k (k+1) \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k-1}=(n-1)^{n-1} n^{3-n} (5 n-3)$$ and for large values of $n$
$$S_n=\frac 1e\left(5 n^3-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{24}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{95}{1152 n}+\frac{917}{11520
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$ which seems to be quite different; however, none of these match the numbers that you provided as examples.